# How can I scale my kafka cluster messages/sec receive up?

Tags: apache-kafka

I try to scale msgs/sec up. I use rdkafka_performance from librdkafka to produce and send messages to my Kafka Cluster. For 1 rdkafka_performance app it can send 1.3m msgs/sec to my Cluster. So I use 9 rdkafka_performance apps to send messages to my cluster (It should produce around 10m msgs/sec). In my cluster for 3 brokers it can receive 7m msgs/sec. but when I add 1 more broker the result still be 7m msgs/sec.
So can I scale the number of messages/sec up by adding the number of broker? or it can not?

Thank you.

Comment: To how many topics are you sending the data?

Comment: I send to 1 topic with 3 partitions when I have 3 brokers and I send to 1 topic with 4 partition when I add one more broker. The results are the same.